# How to Update UI when user cancelled IAP ios sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, in-app-purchase

I have successfully implemented `IAP` in `ios` sdk.

But the problem is when user click on Restore purchase button I initiate the restore by this code:

```
 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

And also I have written this code to handle and initiate the `purchase`:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions){
    switch(transaction.transactionState){

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing: NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchasing");
            //called when the user is in the process of purchasing, do not add any of your own code here.
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            //this is called when the user has successfully purchased the package 
              [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
             [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            [self doRemoveAds]; //you can add your code for what you want to happen when the user buys the purchase here, for this tutorial we use removing ads


            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
             [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");
            //add the same code as you did from SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased here
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
             [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

            //called when the transaction does not finish
            if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled){
                [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Cancelled");
                //the user cancelled the payment ;(
            }
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
    }
}
 }
```

When I select Restore then A dialogs come which ask for password. When I cancel it The progress hud doesn't hides.

How can I do this. How to update UI when user cancel purchase in between the process.

Here is the image. [image]

**EDIT** now when i use the delegate method

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue   restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

}
```

When It asks for password the `SVProgressHUD` hides. No matter I press cancel or OK. How to handle this.

And How to update the `UI` and continue Purchase when user enters correct password.

Comment: Can you determine where it is hiding? You seem to be hiding it both when restore fails and when it succeeds (`SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`). When exactly do your `SVProgressHUD` to dismiss?

Comment: when i click on restore a SVProgressHUD comes... and when it asks for password it hides ( Due to the delegate) but when I enter the correct password nothing happens

Comment: That would happen if the test user hadn't purchased a non-consumable in the past. If you want to know when restore has completed, implement  `- paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished`, but understand that just tells you the restore action is complete, not that anything was restored. `updatedTransactions` will let you know if a non-consumable was restored and should be awarded.

Answer (score 1):

Your delegate should implement this method:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
```

The error in this case will indicate a cancel action.

Comment: and will I have to set delegate of Payment ?